# MySQL database import successful but doesn't work

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, localhost, mamp

I am updating an existing wordpress website for a client and would like to work on it on my local server, but can't seem to get the database to import correctly. I am using MAMP, with phpMyAdmin.

After creating a new folder with a new install of wordpress on my computer, I imported the .sql.gz database backup from the live site into the local database (via phpMyAdmin). I used the same name for the database as on the live site. Got the message: "Import has been successfully finished, 278 queries executed." When I go to the website, or the WP dashboard, nothing seemed to import. None of the pages, posts, menus, or anything. I checked the wp-config.php, and it is referring to the correct database. So what am I doing wrong? How can I get all the content and settings to show?

Comment: Can you check the specific tables to see what got imported? Maybe something is missing so WP won't read it.

Comment: What do you get when you go to the url? a new installation wizard?

Comment: sometimes the MySQL version affect the import and export, is your DB too big?

Comment: The original DB is 58 tables, with 5,420 rows total. After importing it into the local DB, it was also 58 tables. After that, there was a new installation wizard, yeah. Looking at it now, it says 69 tables on the local DB, so maybe more were added after I installed wordpress. I am using MySQL version 5.5.25 on the local server, and the live site is using HostGator's Cpanel which supposedly uses "5.5.21 or higher".

Comment: Got in touch with hostgator and they are using MySQL v 5.5.23.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update some information ...

set wp_options table id 1, 34 change it your local server name...

and then goto your admin dashboard ... deactivate the plugins and then activate them to work on local server.

hope this helps...

Comment: There is no wp_options table in the database on the live site. Maybe I am using the wrong database, but the wp-config.php points to this database.

Comment: Ah, figured out that the prefix was changed to cp_ so the wp_options table was renamed cp_options.

Comment: apologies for the table prefix, i've fixed it, in your case its whatever you set on wp install.

Comment: I was also trying to import a database with different prefix. For anyone else, update $table_prefix in your wp-config.php file.

Answer (score 0):

When you import the database you will also need to import the xml file from wordpress. All you're really importing are the tags and images etc stored in the database but you will need to export your file from localhost and import into the actual server and you will see all of your posts etc.